# "anynchronous" return of a function inside a block

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c-blocks

I have tested several times to take a screenshot on Cocos2D. The only one that works for me is by adding this category to the project:

**HEADER**

```
/*
 * CCNode+Screenshot for cocos2d: https://github.com/pedrohub/
 *
 * Created by Martin Walsh on 23/08/2012.
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Pedro LTD http://www.visitpedro.com All rights reserved.
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 */

#import "CCNode.h"

typedef void (^ScreenshotCompletionBlock)        (UIImage *image);

@interface CCNode (Screenshot)

@property(nonatomic, copy) ScreenshotCompletionBlock completionBlock;

-(void) getScreenshot:(ScreenshotCompletionBlock) block;
-(void) screenshot:(ccTime) dt;

@end
```

IMPLEMENTATION

```
/*
 * CCNode+Screenshot for cocos2d: https://github.com/pedrohub/
 *
 * Created by Martin Walsh on 23/08/2012.
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Pedro LTD http://www.visitpedro.com All rights reserved.
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 * Description : Take a screenshot
 * Installation: Simply drop both files into your project and add #import "CCNode+Screenshot.h" were required.
 *
 * Supported   : iOS4+, cocos2d 2.0, (Unofficial) cocos2d 1.0 (See Below)
 * ARC         : Works with ARC & Non-Arc
 * Tested      : iOS5 Simulator (All Devices)
 *               iPhone (Retina) 5.1
 *
 * Example:
 * [self getScreenshot:^(UIImage *image){
 *      CCLOG(@"Saving Screenshot to Photo Album");
 *      UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, nil, nil);
 *  }];
 * 
 * Misc:
 * Any questions you can find me (@cocojoe) on the cocos2d forum: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/ 
 */

#import "CCNode+Screenshot.h"
#import "CCDirector.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static char SCREENSHOTBLOCK_KEY;

@implementation CCNode (Screenshot)

@dynamic completionBlock;

-(void) getScreenshot:(ScreenshotCompletionBlock) block;
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &SCREENSHOTBLOCK_KEY, block, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
    // Will be black screen if not scheduled
    [self scheduleOnce:@selector(screenshot:) delay:0];
}

#pragma mark Private API
-(void) screenshot:(ccTime) dt
{

    // cocos2d 1.0, change 'view' to 'openGLView'
    UIView * eagleView = (UIView*)[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view];
    GLint backingWidth, backingHeight;

    // Bind the color renderbuffer used to render the OpenGL ES view
    // If your application only creates a single color renderbuffer which is already bound at this point,
    // this call is redundant, but it is needed if you're dealing with multiple renderbuffers.
    // Note, replace "_colorRenderbuffer" with the actual name of the renderbuffer object defined in your class.
    // In Cocos2D the render-buffer is already binded (and it's a private property...).
    //  glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, _colorRenderbuffer);

    // Get the size of the backing CAEAGLLayer
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &backingHeight);

    NSInteger x = 0, y = 0, width = backingWidth, height = backingHeight;
    NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
    GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));

    // Read pixel data from the framebuffer
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
    glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    // Create a CGImage with the pixel data
    // If your OpenGL ES content is opaque, use kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast to ignore the alpha channel
    // otherwise, use kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
    CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate (
                                     width,
                                     height,
                                     8,
                                     32,
                                     width * 4,
                                     colorspace,
                                     // Fix from Apple implementation
                                     // (was: kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast).
                                     kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
                                     ref,
                                     NULL,
                                     true,
                                     kCGRenderingIntentDefault
                                     );

    // OpenGL ES measures data in PIXELS
    // Create a graphics context with the target size measured in POINTS
    NSInteger widthInPoints, heightInPoints;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
    {
        // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
        // Set the scale parameter to your OpenGL ES view's contentScaleFactor
        // so that you get a high-resolution snapshot when its value is greater than 1.0
        CGFloat scale = eagleView.contentScaleFactor;
        widthInPoints = width / scale;
        heightInPoints = height / scale;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints), NO, scale);
    }

    CGContextRef cgcontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // UIKit coordinate system is upside down to GL/Quartz coordinate system
    // Flip the CGImage by rendering it to the flipped bitmap context
    // The size of the destination area is measured in POINTS
    CGContextSetBlendMode(cgcontext, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGContextDrawImage(cgcontext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, widthInPoints, heightInPoints), iref);

    // Retrieve the UIImage from the current context
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Clean up
    free(data);
    CFRelease(ref);
    CFRelease(colorspace);
    CGImageRelease(iref);

    // Block Execution
    ScreenshotCompletionBlock completionBlock = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &SCREENSHOTBLOCK_KEY);
    completionBlock(image);

}

@end
```

and doing this:

```
[myScene getScreenshot:^(UIImage *image){

       // image will contain the screenshot...

}];
```

I can do whatever I want with the screnshot inside this block but not outside. I mean, I need this block to return an image, something like

```
- (UIImage *) shot {

  __block UIImage *screenshot = nil;

    [myScene getScreenshot:^(UIImage *image){

           // image will contain the screenshot...
           screenshot = image;

    }];

   return screenshot;
}
```

Currently this will not work because the line return screenshot will be run before the screenshot is taken and I cannot put this line inside the block.

How do I solve this? I am not that proficient in blocks yet.

thanks.

now suppose what I needed was making this block to return the image asynchronously.

Comment: have you tried: screenshot = [image copy]; ?

Comment: how can this help? if the block is asynchronous what guarantees do I have the "return screenshot" will return the result given inside the block when it is executed?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to implement the same pattern, and expose the completion block to the caller:

```
-(void) shotWithCompletionBlock:(ScreenshotCompletionBlock)completionBlock
{
    [myScene getScreenshot:completionBlock];
}
```

Alternatively you could notify the caller by having him pass in a notification target (use of @protocol is recommended, omitted for brevity):

```
-(void) shotWithNotificationTarget:(id)target
{
    if ([target respondsToSelector:@selector(heyYourScreenshotsReady:)])
    {
        [myScene getScreenshot:^(UIImage *image){
            [target heyYourScreenshotsReady:image];
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code to handle the image - whatever it is - goes *into* the block. Don't hesitate to put any code you want into the block, say saving it to a file, sending it to a server, assigning it a property of some object, or whatever. The block is there to handle exactly this.